# How can I upgrade my 10.7.5 mac to a newer version when it can't even read the disk image InstallMacOSX?

Tags: mac, macos, upgrade

I have a 2006 Mac Pro (MacPro 1,1) with 4GB RAM running OS X Lion (10.7.5)

I've been using this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210717,  to try and upgrade my computer. I've successfully downloaded the file (InstallMacOSX.dmg) from step 4, but whenever I try to open the file to install it onto my computer, my computer tells me that it can't read it due to it not being recognizable.

[image]

I've tried using disk utility to open it via Image>Verify, but it still didn't open it for the same reason. What can I do?

Comment: Which Mac do you have specifically?

Comment: It's a Mac OS X, Version 10.7.5, a Lion. I'm not sure how else to describe my computer apart from the processor and memory found in "About This Mac"

Comment: Figured you had Lion, but we need to know which Mac model, so yes, the info from "About this Mac" would be really helpful

Comment: Mac Pro, Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63b), Serial #: RM6431Y2UQ2, Processor  2 x 2.66 GHz Dual-Core Intel Xeon, Memory  4 GB 667 MHz DDR2 FB-DIMM, hope this helps at all

Answer (score 2):

**Your Mac is not compatible.**

The Mac Pro 1,1 was released in 2006.  Yosemite requires the Mac Pro 3,1 (2008) or later.  Unfortunately, you are at the latest version of OS X that your Mac will support.  See [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-3.0-specs.html) for full details:

> This system can run the last version of OS X 10.7 "Lion" if upgraded to at least 2 GB of RAM. However, although it has a 64-bit processor, it has a 32-bit EFI and cannot boot in 64-bit mode. It also does not support "OpenCL" running the default video card or the other build-to-order video cards that were offered via custom configuration. Please also note that OS X Lion is not capable of running Mac OS X apps originally written for the PowerPC processor as it does not support the "Rosetta" environment.